# How do I edit my profile?

Tags: support, user-profile, stack-exchange

I wasn't entirely sure where to ask this, but this was the best place I could think of.
I'm trying to edit my profile on stack exchange, but I can't figure out how. I've matured a lot since I created it, so I want to change my username and my description thing to something more mature.

P.S. I'm on a phone, not my usual laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to your Profile by clicking on your picture on the top bar, then click on 'Edit Profile'.

Or, follow this link: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

Comment: The edit button doesn't show up for me, cause I'm on the mobile app, but the link worked

Comment: @ZachTalonGamesYT Good to know, glad you got there in the end :)

Comment: Tried https://stackexchange.com/users/edit/current and that was a "page not found". There is no Edit button on my stackexchange user page. What the gleep?

Comment: @Urhixidur It doesn't look like you can set a Network-wide profile bio that's different from a site bio. On your [Stack Exchange profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), there's a link to 'Update Profile Info' under the bio on the right, but when clicked it opens a prompt to copy the bio from a particular site.

Comment: @Robotnik Indeed. That interface is seriously lacking. It should indicate from where the current profile was last copied, and the button should be more clearly labelled "Import profile info". And the import dialog should highlight the last-used site and those sites that actually have a profile to copy from. A preview or undo facility would be nice.

Comment: @Urhixidur Might be a good idea to raise a feature request like that on Meta Stack Exchange - although I don't think stackexchange.com is high on the company's priorities.